# How do I detect a row I have tapped that was inserted via a MultivaluedSection in Eureka form builder?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I can successfully insert TextAreaRow(s) in the MultivaluedSection and each is given a unique name using a string plus the index.  I would like to be able to intercept when someone taps on one of these newly inserted rows as I would like to perform some additional actions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to intercept when someone taps on one of these newly inserted rows as I would like to perform some additional actions.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#callbacks-list), Eureka has callback `onCellSelection()` which:

> Called each time the user taps on the row and it gets selected.

Basically, you need to describe your changes in this callback:

```
AnyRowYouWant { row in
    // init the row
}.onCellSelection { cell, row in
    // handle tap right here
}
```